# Record call stack and values on breakpoint?

Tags: memory-leaks, windbg, breakpoints, visual-studio-debugging, callstack

#### Background

I'm trying to track down a memory leak issue, where I know (from _CRT_DEBUG_MALLOC and MFC's and the CRT's leak detection) the specific line of where memory is leaked, but since this line is invoked so often, I do not know which call actually leaks. And the Allocation-Number + `__p__crtBreakAlloc()` doesn't help, because it's a different allocation number each run.

Anyways, so far for background. If you think I should be using a different tool, please leave a comment. I would appreciate if **answers concentrate on the actual question** instead of my underlying problem, as I find that much more interesting than the leak itself (I'll find that eventually through enough poking).

### Question

Is it possible in WinDbg (I'm pretty sure it ain't in VS) to have a breakpoint with the following properties:

- It doesn't break. (So it's a "tracepoint")
- When hit, it records the call stack (up to a certain depth)
- It should also record some global state (variables, maybe just the raw value of a memory address)

Is this possible? How?

Comment: What you describe sounds like very inefficient way to locate leaks. Did you try using [UMDH tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558947(v=vs.85).aspx)? You can easily obtain call stack of the leaking allocation with UMDH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer each of your question points:

- breakpoint without breaking:

  `bp myDll!<namespace>::myClass::myFunc "gc"` - you can execute commands delimited by double quotes, in this case when the breakpoint is hit, just continue
- on hitting breakpoint dump the call stack up a certain depth

  `.kframes 0n50; bp myDll!<namespace>::myClass::myFunc "kb;gc"` - this sets the call stack length to 50 (the default is 20), the `0n` tells it we are decimal based. the command in double quotes after `bp` will dump the call stack and then continue
- record some global state

  `dt myVar` - will display global variables, additionally so will using `d* myVar`

  `dd myGlobalVar`

  make sure pdbs do not have private symbols stripped - you should check the info for [`dt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff542772%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as there are specific switches to handle unicode strings, depths etc.., additionally you can easily observe the values in the watch window in [WinDbg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439485%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), plus see the doc about [`d*`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff542790%28v=vs.85%29)

Additionally there is an automated leak detection command in WinDbg:

```
!heap -l
```

but I have found it a bit hit and miss sometimes, more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff563189%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Note that it's better to use the `gc` command to continue from a breakpoint, because if you're manually stepping and you hit a breakpoint with a `g` at the end, it'll act like you hit F5 to continue executing normally. The `gc` command continues in the same manner as when the breakpoint was hit: if you're stepping, you keep stepping; if execution was running normally, execution will continue normally.

Comment: Also, the `k` command can take a number of frames to show, so you don't need to run `.kframes` first, if you want to see a different number of frames: `kb 0n50`

Comment: @KurtHutchinson yes that is true but I like to have a very deep callstack from the word go and most people are not aware that it defaults to 20

Comment: @KurtHutchinson yes that is a good point about preferring `gc` over `g`, I will update my answer, thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying is a really brute-force approach that has very little positive effect when dealing with memory leaks - at least something like UMDH is necessary to cope with the complexity of tracking the leak down based on stack traces. Even if you succeed taking a few traces it's likely to be overly verbose for you to handle manually.

There's a generic debugger extension to track all kinds of leaks which will give you a bit of leverage if you go the manual route: [domdbg extension](http://www.denismo.name/domdbg/WebPages/MainPage.htm)

There's a helper python script I wrote you might find useful if you go the UMDH path - it helps you automate taking snapshots a bit and can be more efficient when analyzing the traces since it will cache symbol information and will store the traces in binary form (as opposed to textual representation used by UMDH): [pyumdh](https://github.com/a-palchikov/pyumdh)

Answer (score 1):

There's also a [tracer extension](https://github.com/goldshtn/windbg-extensions) that can track arbitrary open and close operations.